# iPhone Connection problems to web server on local network

Tags: ios, web, server, connection

We are currently on a ship, the ship has a web server to give details of the ship's services.

On ios 15 passengers have to turn Wi-Fi on and mobile data off.

Sometimes the iPhone won't connect to the webserver. Even using the IP address of the webserver does work.

Restarting the phone does work.

Has anyone any thoughts on what happening and a possible solution?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check that all iPhones get a different IP address after wifi connection ? iPhones use a random Mac-address when connecting to wifi, so thar may be why restarting iPhone may work.

Comment: You should ask this question in [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) of stack exchange